# recursion problem with nested lists in python

Tags: python, recursion, nested

I have the following code:

```
def flat_list(array):
    d=[]
    for i in array:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            d.append(i)
        else:
            flat_list(i)
    return d
```

When I call `flat_list([1, [2, 2, 2], 4])`, I expect it to return unpacked list ([1, 2, 2, 2, 4]). Instead it returns ([1, 4]). Although, if I try `(print i)` instead of `(d.append(i))`, it returns unpacked i.

I read [an article](https://hackernoon.com/recursion-vs-looping-in-python-9261442f70a5) about recursion, it says return needs to be after base condition.

How do I use kindda (`return d.append(i)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you call your function, but don't do anything with its return value when calling it recursively

```
    else:
        d.extend(flat_list(i))
```

`extend` will take all the items from the list that `flat_list` returns, and adds them to your list you are creating within the function

[Example](https://ideone.com/wsQKFN)

Comment: I have the same problem using yield. Could you, please, suggest a solution?       def flat_list(array):
  
    for i in array:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            yield i
        else:
            flat_list(i)

Comment: @KamalValikhanov - You should ask it as a new question with what you've tried and researched