# recursion problem with nested lists using yield in python

Tags: python, recursion, nested, yield

I have a code as below and I need it to unpack lists using yield:

```
def flat_list(array):
    d=[]
    for i in array:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            yield i
        else:
            flat_list(i)
```

For example, `flat_list([1, [2, 2, 2], 4])` should return `[1, 2, 2, 2, 4]`. My code returns `[1, 4]`.

I understand from previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606878/recursion-problem-with-nested-lists-in-python) that I need not only recursively call a function, but to specify what it should do.

But how do you add `flat_list(i)` items to `yield` items? Something like `flat_list(i).extend(yield i)`.

Comment: `d` is unused. You don't need to fill a list in your function when you yield

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should yield all of the items generated by the `flat_list(i)` call. You can do this with `yield from`.

```
def flat_list(array):
    for i in array:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            yield i
        else:
            yield from flat_list(i)

for x in flat_list([1, [2, 2, 2], 4]):
    print(x)
```

Result:

```
1
2
2
2
4
```

Comment: What's `d=[]` for?

Comment: mistake, from old draft code